javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Elemento no esperado usando Java 8
Desde mi aplicación en Java8 estoy llamando a un WS de SOAP que me devuelve lo siguiente:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <DescargarMensajeOut xmlns="https://descargarmensaje.servicio.xxxxx.es">
            <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
            <mensajeWS xmlns="https://xxxxx/3.27">
                <respuestaGetBloque xmlns="">
                    <idBloqueEntregado>0</idBloqueEntregado>
                    <esUltimo>false</esUltimo>
                    <bytesContenido>DATOENBASE64</bytesContenido>
                </respuestaGetBloque>
            </mensajeWS>]]>
        </DescargarMensajeOut>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

El cual serán guardados en el siguiente objeto de Java:
@XmlRootElement(name = "respuestaGetBloque")
public class BloqueDescargado {

    private int idBloqueEntregado;
    
    private boolean esUltimo;
    
    private byte[] bytesContenido;
    
    public BloqueDescargado() {
        this.idBloqueEntregado = 0;
        this.esUltimo = false;
        this.bytesContenido = new byte[0];
    }

    //Metodos Get y Set

}

El método que utilizo para mapear los datos es el siguiente (siendo String xml los datos que devuelve SOAP):
private BloqueDescargado pasarXMLtoObject(String xml) {
        BloqueDescargado bloqueDescargado = new BloqueDescargado();
        
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BloqueDescargado.class);
            
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            
            bloqueDescargado = (BloqueDescargado) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
            
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            log.error("JAXBException. Problemas en mapear el xml en objeto bloqueDescargado, motivo: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return bloqueDescargado;
    }

El problema es que cuando guardo los datos en bloqueDescargado se produce el siguente error:

[28/08/24 10:36:26:334 CEST] 000000c2 SystemErr     R
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Elemento no esperado
"idBloqueEntregado". Los elementos esperados son "respuestaGetBloque".
[28/08/24 10:36:26:335 CEST] 000000c2 SystemErr     R     at
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.msg.JAXBMessageProvider.throwUnmarshalExceptionWrapper(JAXBMessageProvider.java:93)
[28/08/24 10:36:26:335 CEST] 000000c2 SystemErr     R     at
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.DeserializationContext.handleSkippedRootElementEvent(DeserializationContext.java:341)
[28/08/24 10:36:26:335 CEST] 000000c2 SystemErr     R     at
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.JAXBDocumentScanner.produceRootElementEvent(JAXBDocumentScanner.java:189)

